# \columncolor overwrites table lines

Tags: tables, beamer, color

When I fill columns of my table with a color, it overwrites some of the lines. Is there a way to avoid it?

```
\documentclass[slidetop,11.5pt,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}


\begin{document}



\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    $\rightarrow$ blablabla\\
     \begin{tabular}{c }
    \\
    \end{tabular}
        \fontsize{7.5}{7}\selectfont

    %changes the font size to 6 points and the \baselineskip to 7.2 points


    {%\centering
    \makebox[\textwidth]
    {
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.8cm} r >{\columncolor{gray}}r r >{\columncolor{gray}}r r >{\columncolor{gray}}r r >{\columncolor{gray}}r r >{\columncolor{gray}}r }
    \hhline{*{11}{-}}
    \raggedright & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C4} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Total}\\
    \hhline{\arrayrulecolor{black}-----------}
     & nb & \% col & nb & \% col & nb & \% col & nb & \% col & nb & \% col\\\hhline{*{11}{-}}
Q5 for both  &  184 & 1,6 & 2011 & 15,8 & 2762 & 23,4 & 1121 & 14 & 6078 & \textbf{13,7}
\\ \hhline{\arrayrulecolor{black}-----------}
Q1-Q4 for F, Q5 for E & 32 & 0,3 & 414 & 3,3 & 660 & 5,6 & 1685 & 21,1 & 2791 & \textbf{6,3}\\
 \hline
Q5 for F, Q1-Q4 for E & 1746 & 14,8 & 833 & 6,5 & 214 & 1,8 &   &   & 2793 & \textbf{6,3}
\\ \hline
Q1-Q4 for both  & 9855 & 83,4 & 9465 & 74,4 & 8166 & 69,2 & 5197 & 64,9 & 32683 & \textbf{73,7}
\\ \hhline{\arrayrulecolor{black}-----------}
Total & 11817 & 100 & 12723 & 100 & 11802 & 100 & 8003 & 100 & 44345 & 100
\\ \hhline{\arrayrulecolor{black}-----------}
    \end{tabular}%
    }\par
    }

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\fontsize{7.5}{7}\selectfont` specifies a 7.5pt font on a 7pt baseline which isn't an achievable constraint so will generate inconsistent linespacing

Comment: If both `xcolor` and `colortable` are needed, don't load them separately. Instead, issue the directive `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` to load them in a mutually compatible manner.

Answer (score 1):

I have some immediate suggestions:

- Don't use both `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}` and the font-size changing command to try to make the table fit inside the text block. Providing the instructions `\tiny` and `\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt}` should suffice to make the table fit.
- All of the `\hhline{...}` instructions can be replaced with `\hline`.
- I'd change the column colors from "gray" to "lightgray".
- If you need to load both the `xcolor` and the `colortable` packages, you should do so with the single instruction `\usepackage[table]{color}`. See page 9 of the user guide of the `xcolor` package for an explanation.

[image]

Even with these changes, I'd say the table is not all that readable, and various table features -- such as the fact that the numbers in the final column are typeset in bold -- are not easy to spot. Rather than use gray-striping of the columns, I'd provide more structure to the header, get rid of the distracting interior horizontal lines, and use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package for the remaining lines. I'd also increase the font size from `\tiny` to `\scriptsize` (and, to compensate, reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace). I think your readers will appreciate the larger lettering.

[image]

```
\documentclass[slidetop,11.5pt,xcolor=table]{beamer}
%%\usepackage{tikz}   
%%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % see p. 9 of UG of xcolor package
%%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\usepackage{booktabs,array,ragged2e}  % for second table
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\arraybackslash\RaggedRight}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]  % "[t]" just for this example
\frametitle{Title}

\tiny  % use a built-in LaTeX font size command
\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt}  % default: 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}

\begin{tabular}{@{} p{1.8cm} 
           *{5}{r >{\columncolor{lightgray}}r} }
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{C1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C2} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{C3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C4} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Total}\\
\hline
& nb & \% col & nb & \% col & nb & \% col & nb & \% col & nb & \% col\\
\hline
Q5 for both  &  184 & 1,6 & 2011 & 15,8 & 2762 & 23,4 & 1121 & 14 & 6078 & \textbf{13,7} \\ 
\hline
Q1--Q4 for F, Q5 for E & 32 & 0,3 & 414 & 3,3 & 660 & 5,6 & 1685 & 21,1 & 2791 & \textbf{6,3}\\
\hline
Q5 for F, Q1--Q4 for E & 1746 & 14,8 & 833 & 6,5 & 214 & 1,8 &   &   & 2793 & \textbf{6,3}\\ 
\hline
Q1--Q4 for both  & 9855 & 83,4 & 9465 & 74,4 & 8166 & 69,2 & 5197 & 64,9 & 32683 & \textbf{73,7} \\ 
\hline
Total & 11817 & 100 & 12723 & 100 & 11802 & 100 & 8003 & 100 & 44345 & 100 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]  % "[t]" just for this example
\frametitle{Another Title}

\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}  % default: 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % 2.2 seems excessive...

\begin{tabular}{@{} P{1.7cm} *{10}{r} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{C1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C2} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{C3} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C4} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Total}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(l){10-11} 
& nb & \%col & nb & \%col & nb & \%col & nb & \%col & nb & \%col\\
\midrule
Q5 for both  &  184 & 1,6 & 2011 & 15,8 & 2762 & 23,4 & 1121 & 14 & 6078 & \textbf{13,7} \\ 
Q1--Q4 for F, Q5 for E & 32 & 0,3 & 414 & 3,3 & 660 & 5,6 & 1685 & 21,1 & 2791 & \textbf{6,3}\\
Q5 for F, Q1--Q4 for E & 1746 & 14,8 & 833 & 6,5 & 214 & 1,8 &   &   & 2793 & \textbf{6,3}\\ 
Q1--Q4 for both  & 9855 & 83,4 & 9465 & 74,4 & 8166 & 69,2 & 5197 & 64,9 & 32683 & \textbf{73,7} \\ 
Total & 11817 & 100 & 12723 & 100 & 11802 & 100 & 8003 & 100 & 44345 & 100 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```